# Change nav text on hover than change back to original text

Tags: jquery, cufon

I am using cufon and I am trying to figure out how to change navigation text on `hover/mouse over` then change back to the original text on `mouse out/hover off`. Right now when I hover over the nav tab that I want the text change it does but it doesn't change back to the original text, color or font.

Here is a link to my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/4fPw6/

Basically I need "fall" in the nav to change to "coming soon" when the user hovers over or mouse over and when the user hovers off or mouse outs the text will change back to "fall"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks so much guys!

Comment: There are a number of issues with your jsFiddle. 1. You haven't selected jQuery as the framework (top left). 2. You've included `<script>` tags in the JavaScript panel (this is invalid). 3. You're trying to load JS files that are local to your server using relative URLs (this won't work).

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle to correct the above issues as best I can - http://jsfiddle.net/4fPw6/1/ - and it seems to work as you want now; the issue on your actual page is possibly to do with cufon.

Comment: I also updated your fiddle, but I fixed a few other things.  1) Combining all of the links into a single definition.  2) Using line-height to set the height of the buttons.  3) Applying the width to the inner anchor tag.  4) Applying the jquery hover to the anchor, so the link doesn't disappear when you hover.  Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/4fPw6/4/

Comment: Thanks guys for the help... this is exactly what I was trying to do! Much appreciated for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your script tags should be in the HTML and you need to include JQuery to make use of its functions.

Also you were modifying the text of `.fall` which is an li element and doesn't contain any text. You have to target the `<a>` tag inside it that contains the text you want to modify.

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/4fPw6/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way using [CSS only](http://jsfiddle.net/4fPw6/3/) (bit hacky though):

```
.fall:hover:before {
    content: 'coming soon';
    font-size: 0.875em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
.fall:hover a {
    display: none;
}
```